# Try Catch or Boolean check

Tags: java, try-catch

Let's say I have the following code:

```
void validate(File f) //or boolean?????
{
  ...
  try
  {
    //try to validate xml file
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
  }
}

...

try
{

  validate(xml_file); //validates XML file
  move(xml_file, valid_folder); //moves valid XML file to valid_folder
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  move(xml_file, error_folder); //moves invalid XML file to error_folder
}

...
```

Should my `validate()` function be `boolean` and I should check whether file is valid XML file or not or `catching` will do it for me?

Comment: both variants will work. In your situation, where you want to move it to folder A if it's valid and to folder B if not, I prefer `if/else` over `try/catch`. Also I wouldn't `catch (Exception`, I'd only catch specific ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem you might want to think about is the single responsibility principle: a method should do one thing well.

Your validate method is doing at least three things:

1. Reading XML from a file
2. Validating that XML in some unspecified way
3. Moving the file to one folder or another, depending on outcome

Perhaps you'll have an easier time if you break these up.

What if someone wants to validate XML without moving the file?  Your method can't be called in that case.

Even validating is questionable.  If you check against a schema you'll throw an exception on the first issue.  Would users want to know ALL the problems at once?  If yes, you'll have to walk the tree and find all the errors yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Exceptions should not be used to control the normal flow of your program. They slow down execution considerably when they occur. Your program wants to sort valid XML files from invalid XML files. So you're expecting the occurrence of invalid XML files, which is why you're sorting them into different files. Therefore, you should return a boolean rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: Well, most of the time the slow down of execution time is not really something to worry about. They do slow *me* down during the execution of an application, as exceptions are also caught by the debugger. Much more important. In the normal flow of an application you should not get exceptions, unless unavoidable.

Comment: The slow down is not something to worry about if exceptions are used properly. If you're having exceptions being thrown on a regular basis then you're going to feel it. The normal flow of an program should not get an exception, period. Throwing an exception means the normal flow of the program cannot continue for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If it returns `boolean`, it would look cleaner and simpler:

```
if(validate(xml_file)) move(xml_file, valid_folder);
else move(xml_file, error_folder);
```

However, your solution (throwing the exception) could carry a lot of information about the thrown exception that you can pass to `move()` method. Or alternatively `validate()` method returns `int` in which each value indicates specific state.

Comment: Working with error codes should really be avoided. The only time I work with them is when an external interface requires them (e.g. Java has enum, which is better suited). If you need to carry more information then simply create a `Result` class, but don't put an exception in the normal flow of the application for that reason alone.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it as boolean. You can add boolean variable (initially true) at the start of the validate method and inside catch you can set it to false. At the end of the function, return the boolean variable value. So if your code inside the try block encounters an exception, you handle it by setting the boolean variable to false so that your method returns false if exception encountered, true otherwise.