# return boolean or try catch

Tags: java, oop

when a function or method encouter error/invalid data, do return false or throw an exception?
Consider a class Loginer has such method :

```
public boolean login(String username){
    //retrieve data...
    if(username.equals(record.username)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

then at the main or some other class

```
String username = "ggwp";
if(Loginer.login(username)){
    //successful login, show homepage...
    new User(username);
} else {
    //invalid username
}
```

won't it be inefficient as it has been checked two time with if-else statement, one in Loginer, and another one check for true again at main.
won't try catch will do the same? having the Loginer to throw an Exception:

```
public User login(String username){
    //retrieve record data...
    if(username.equals(record.username)){
        return new User(username);
    }

    /* Exception if no record found for such username */
    throw new MyException("invalid username");
}
```

then on the main:

```
String username = "ggwp2";
User theUser;
try{
    //sucessful login
    theUser = Loginer.login(username);
}catch(MyException e){
    //invalid username
}
```

the try-catch need no check second time for true or false. (this example i use return User object, it could be void and return nothing but the point is, why use boolean which will eventual being check twice?)

some website sources say not to use try-catch for 'code jumping' but in this case it just do the same. (try-catch is just too similar to if-else statement)

So which is correct and why? please guide and sorry if this question is incorrect, im newbie to OO.

Comment: Use exceptions to handle exceptional conditions only. If you can predict and detect the problem, there is no need to use an exception.

Comment: There is the option of returning `Optional<User>` which is only filled if valid, empty otherwise.

Comment: Any opposition to closing this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972307/when-to-return-bool-throw-an-exception-and-which-exception-to-throw ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer:

You should *NEVER* use try/catch for "control logic".

As  Andy Turner said, "Use exceptions to handle exceptional conditions only."

This is equally true of all languages that support exceptions - not just Java. Useful article:

[Best practices for exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions)

PS: try/catch is *NOT* "just similar" to "if/else".  It has a different implementation, a different intent ... and it's *FAR* more expensive.

ADDITIONAL NOTE:

> *Exceptions: Why throw early? Why catch late?*
>
> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231057/exceptions-why-throw-early-why-catch-late
>
> In my experience, its best to throw exceptions at the point where the
>   errors occur. You do this because it's the point where you know the
>   most about why the exception was triggered.
>
> As the exception unwinds back up the layers, catching and rethrowing
>   is a good way to add additional context to the exception. This can
>   mean throwing a different type of exception, but include the original
>   exception when you do this.
>
> Eventually the exception will reach a layer where you are able to make
>   decisions on code flow (e.g a prompt the user for action). This is the
>   point where you should finally handle the exception and continue
>   normal execution.
>
> With practice and experience with your code base it becomes quite easy
>   to judge when to add additional context to errors, and where it's most
>   sensible to actually, finally handle the errors.
>
> - Catch → Rethrow
>
>   Do this where you can usefully add more information that would save
>     a developer having to work through all the layers to understand the
>     problem.
> - Catch → Handle
>
>   Do this where you can make final decisions on what is an
>     appropriate, but different execution flow through the software.
> - Catch → Error Return
>
>   Whilst there are situations where this is appropriate, catching
>     exceptions and returning an error value to the caller should be
>     considered for refactoring into a Catch → Rethrow implementation.

Comment: The "PS" indicated that this was supposed to be a comment (so I won't downvote, just wait until you delete it ;-) )

Comment: Yeah, it was meant to be a comment.  But responses don't completely "delete", so I'll leave it as a response ... and just delete my previous comment instead.  BTW - this post has duplicates, including: [Best practice for Java exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545270/best-practice-for-java-exception-handling) and [Exceptions: Why throw early? Why catch late?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231057/exceptions-why-throw-early-why-catch-late)

Comment: While far more expensive, once this path warms up it costs about 1 microsecond, whereas boolean is a fraction of this, but might not be a problem.

Comment: One final comment: although a good case can be made for throwing a "logon exception" error, I'd just use a boolean.  The reason is that the caller who invoked the logon needs to know directly whether it succeeded or not, and take the appropriate action.  There shouldn't be any need to "bubble" the logon failure to any other part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else finds this, I found another Stack Overflow thread where someone suggested creating a new class to handle this scenario (see [Try Catch or Boolean check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902174/try-catch-or-boolean-check)).

I tried it and it works brilliantly. If-boolean can be a bit simplistic if our method calls other methods that each check one thing. And try-catch should ideally be used for genuine exceptions.

By creating a Result class (e.g. with a boolean property and a String property), we can return the result (true/false) and a meaningful message that can be printed to the console or to a GUI (e.g. JavaFX).